# How can I put something at the end of the URL using jQuery upon clicking a dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery

To give an idea of what I have, I created drop-down content boxes, so that when a certain drop-down is clicked it slides hidden content down below and makes it visible. What I have been trying to figure out is how I can get the drop-down to add something to the end of the url when it is clicked on so that when you send a link to someone else, that particular drop-down is already open.

This is the Javascript/jQuery code that I've tried:

```
$('.dropdown').click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('active')){
        $(this).removeClass('active');
        $(this).next('.dropdown_content').slideUp(300);
    }else{
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $(this).next('.dropdown_content').slideDown(300);
    }
});
```

This is the HTML:

```
<div class="dropdown_wrapper">
   <h3 class="dropdown">Title of Dropdown<span></span></h3>
   <div class="hidden dropdown_content">
      <p>Content</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Post the code that you have (html & javascript) so far.

Comment: I see this done with hash property. window.location.hash